# Re-spawning in different locations (generating new value)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, location, skspritenode

I've got this set of code that spawns a SKSpriteNode within a set location (using rect), but I'm trying to make the Node disappear but then reappear after a set amount of time in a different location. I've been looking a NSTimer but not sure how to implement that, is there a good way of doing this?

```
let rect = CGRectMake(8, 293, 165, 218)    
let x = rect.origin.x + CGFloat(arc4random()) % rect.size.width
let y = rect.origin.y + CGFloat(arc4random()) % rect.size.height
let randomPoint = CGPointMake(x, y)
self.redcircle.position = randomPoint
self.addChild(redcircle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `NSTimer`, use a SpriteKit  `SKAction`. What you need is the action `waitForDuration`:

```
someNode.hidden = YES

waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(someDuration)

self.runAction(wait, completion: {() -> Void in

    // Sprite Kit waits for a certain amount of time and runs this completion closure
    // Inside here you can get the node to reappear again

    someNode.hidden = NO
}))
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a a way to repeat this, so it disappears again and reappears in a different location within the rect?

Comment: Yeah what you could do is use a custom `SKAction` (called `runBlock`) which would make the node unhidden or hidden. Then you would put that action inside of a `sequence` action and have another action repeat that sequence for either a certain amount of iterations or forever. You should check out the SKAction class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/

Comment: Do you know how I would implement the `node.hidden` into the SKAction so it can keep on disappearing and then become unhidden?

Comment: You would need to create a custom SKAction, which would either be a runBlock or performSelector. runBlock might be the easiest since it creates a closure inside which you just write either unhidden or hidden